# What is time complexity of the following sort function?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

I've wrote this code for bubble sort.Can someone explain me the time complexity for this. It is working similar to 2 for loops. But still want to confirm with time complexity.

```
public int[] sortArray(int[] inpArr)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while(i != inpArr.length-1 && j != inpArr.length-1)
    {
        if(inpArr[i] > inpArr[i+1])
        {
            int temp = inpArr[i];
            inpArr[i] = inpArr[i+1];
            inpArr[i+1] = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
        }

        if(i==inpArr.length-1)
        {
            j++;
            i = 0;
        }
    }

    return inpArr;
}
```

Comment: Why the `else`? All it does is cause an extra iteration of the loop whenever a swap is made. You should get rid of the `else`, and increment `i` unconditionally.

Answer (score 2):

This would have O(n^2) time complexity. Actually, this would be probably be both O(n^2) and theta(n^2).

Look at the logic of your code. You are performing the following:

1. Loop through the input array
2. If the current item is bigger than the next, switch the two
3. If that is not the case, increase the index(and essentially check the next item, so recursively walk through steps 1-2)
4. Once your index is the length-1 of the input array, i.e. it has gone through the entire array, your index is reset (the `i=0` line), and j is increased, and the process restarts.

This essentially ensures that the given array will be looped through twice, meaning that you will have a WORST-CASE (big o, or O(x)) time complexity of O(n^2), but given this code, your AVERAGE (theta) time complexity will be theta(n^2).

There are SOME situations where you can have a BEST CASE (lambda) of n*lg(n), giving a lambda(n*lg*(n)) time complexity, but this situation is rare and I'm not even sure its achievable with this code.

Comment: No problem. If you felt this was a good answer, please upvote it and mark it as correct so other users can benefit from your question.

Comment: Please mark this answer is correct if it it did indeed answer your question

Answer (score 0):

Your time complexity is `O(n^2)` as a worst-case scenario and `O(n)` as a best case scenario. Your average scenario still performs O(n^2) comparisons but will have less swaps than O(n^2). This is because you're essentially doing the same thing as having two `for` loops. If you're interested in algorithmic efficiency, I'd recommend checking out pre-existing libraries that sort. The computer scientists that work on these sort of things really are *intense.* Java's `Arrays.sort()` method is based on a Python project called [timsort](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listsort.txt) that is based on merge-sorting. The disadvantage of your (and every) Bubble sort is that it's *really* inefficient for big, disordered arrays. Read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Performance).

Comment: Thanks Furkan for your kind suggestion

Comment: `O(n) as a best case` suggest input that takes less than `n^2` iterations.